How to verify a BTC address was generated by my private and public keys
I created a wallet using a seed phrase and a passphrase. I sent BTC to the first address listed by the wallet The BTC arrived at that address. The wallet is not now listing that address. I have the public and private keys, is it possible to verify that the address holding the BTC is a valid address for those keys?
